# « Comment ça va ? »

Tags: expressions, salutations

J'ai un collègue (d'une soixantaine d'années, s'il est important de le mentionner) qui lorsqu'il me rencontre, me salue en disant :

> Bonjour, comment ça va ?

Il fait ainsi avec les autres collègues que les étudiants.
Quand utilise-t-on « comment ça va » ?
Cette salutation mène-t-elle au tutoiement ?

Comment: Je dirais que ça implique le tutoiement, mais pas obligatoirement non plus. Je pourrais dire ça à quelqu'un que je vais ensuite vouvoyer, mais ça dépend de la personne. L'idéal reste de dire `Comment allez-vous ?` quand on veut vouvoyer.

Comment: Je ne ferai pas de réponse, ce serait hyper subjectif. C'est un truc (tic de langage ?) que chacun manie à sa manière et qui fonctionne différemment selon les groupes sociaux. Je refuse de l'employer à cause de l’ambiguïté. Dans certains groupes que je fréquente l'expression est employée dans son sens premier et le locuteur attend une réponse. Dans d'autres c'est simplement l'équivalent de « bonjour » et si je m'amuse à lui dire « bien, je pète la forme » ou « mal mauvaise journée » la personne me regarde éberluée (la « bonne » réponse est : « bien, et toi ?).

Comment: Pas générationnel et pas lié au tutoiement (Comment allez-vous ? Comment ça va ?) mais cependant familier et à mon avis à ne pas employer avec des gens qu'on ne connaît pas au moins un peu ou avec qui on a des relations très formelles.

Comment: Personnellement, quand je rencontre quelqu'un que je vouvoie, j'utilise systématiquement "comment allez-vous ?", jamais "comment ça va ?". Et j'ai la soixantaine ! (Mais en quoi est-ce important ?). Cela n'implique pas que la deuxième expression implique nécessairement un tutoiement. Simplement elle me semble trop familière pour être employée avec quelqu'un que je vouvoie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Comment ça va ? » est une forme assez familière mais pas tant qu'elle ne puisse pas  être utilisée par quelqu'un qui ne tutoie pas la personne à laquelle elle parle.

*Exemples d'utilisation un peu plus développés*

— Bonjour Monsieur Laurent ! Comment ça va ? Votre femme s'est-elle remise de cette mauvaise grippe ? Vous pensez à vous faire vacciner tous les deux ?

— Comment ça va Monsieur Laurent ? Vous vous êtes bien remis de cette jambe cassée je vois !

— Comment ça va ? On ne vous voit plus souvent par ici Monsieur Laurent ! Qu'est-ce qui vous amène ?

Évidemment, puisque « Comment ça va ? » est un peu familier, si la relation que l'on entretient avec quelqu'un reste sur la base d'une certaine distance, on s'abstient de l'utiliser; seulement « Comment allez-vous ? » convient.